# Repeatedly prompt for username/password when adding Service Reference to SharePoint site from VS2010

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services, sharepoint

I am developing a simple C# winform application which retrieves lists from a SharePoint site. But I encountered a problem when I tried to add service reference to that sharepoint site in VS2010. It keeps on asking me for username and password and does not seem to end.

I have tried to use "wsdl /server" command with same username & password, it generates a C# successfully.

How can I solve the problem? What is the alternative to adding a service reference?

Comment: Are you trying to access a custom service or utilize the SharePoint API services?

Comment: hi matt, it's standard SharePoint API services, not customized.

Comment: Solved. Instead of using https://siteurl/_vti_bin/lists.asmx, use https://siteurl/_vti_bin/lists.asmx?wsdl. After entered username/password once, click on No for the following prompts. A List should be shown under services text field in the end.